How to get list of Users with "Microsoft Teams Phone" license in graph api?
So I have a request, by adding assignedLicenses to the select:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users$select=displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,surname,userPrincipalName,id,assignedLicenses

This returns the user details along with the assignedLicense. BUT THE PROBLEM WITH THIS ONE THE ASSIGNEDLICENSES ONLY RETURNS SkuID.
What I want is to get list of users license details along with the user list. I dont want to loop my users just to get each license details. This could take time if you have many users
We have many customers that has different licenses to them, we want to make sure that some of their user has a "Microsoft team phone" license.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038')/licenseDetails",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "3RnS3Gi8m0u_C0ozp5a-NWAn38eBLPdOtXhbU5K1cd8",
            "skuId": "c7df2760-2c81-4ef7-b578-5b5392b571df",
            "skuPartNumber": "ENTERPRISEPREMIUM",
            "servicePlans": [
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "cd31b152-6326-4d1b-ae1b-997b625182e6",
                    "servicePlanName": "MIP_S_Exchange",
                    "provisioningStatus": "PendingProvisioning",
                    "appliesTo": "User"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "8e0c0a52-6a6c-4d40-8370-dd62790dcd70",
                    "servicePlanName": "THREAT_INTELLIGENCE",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "User"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "9c0dab89-a30c-4117-86e7-97bda240acd2",
                    "servicePlanName": "POWERAPPS_O365_P3",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "User"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "8c098270-9dd4-4350-9b30-ba4703f3b36b",
                    "servicePlanName": "ADALLOM_S_O365",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "User"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72",
                    "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "User"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "3RnS3Gi8m0u_C0ozp5a-Ne0iVHIF4g5Aqwo4mdijmMo",
            "skuId": "725422ed-e205-400e-ab0a-3899d8a398ca",
            "skuPartNumber": "SCHOOL_DATA_SYNC_P2",
            "servicePlans": [
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "113feb6c-3fe4-4440-bddc-54d774bf0318",
                    "servicePlanName": "EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "500b6a2a-7a50-4f40-b5f9-160e5b8c2f48",
                    "servicePlanName": "SCHOOL_DATA_SYNC_P2",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "User"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Or is Their a way to get all users, and also filter it to get only the users that have "Microsoft Teams Phone" license?

Have you tried to filter users by assignedPlans?
GET /v1.0/users?$select=displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,surname,userPrincipalName,id,assignedPlans&$filter=assignedPlans/any(a:a/servicePlanId eq <guid>)&$count=true

GET /v1.0/users?$select=displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,surname,userPrincipalName,id,assignedPlans&$filter=assignedPlans/any(a:a/service eq '<service_plan_name>')&$count=true

You need to add ConsistencyLevel header with the value eventual
